# Error when trying to access a nullable association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I have two entities, `Aufgabe` and `Version` with a oneToMany-Relation (One `Version` can have many `Aufgaben`), buts it's **optional**, means an `Aufgabe` needn't have a `Version` assigned. Here is the YAML mapping for both of them:

Version:

```
evenos\Bundle\TimeBundle\Entity\Version:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: evenos\Bundle\TimeBundle\Repository\VersionRepository
    table: version

    id: 
        id:
            type: integer 
        Projekt:
            associationKey: true

    fields:
        nummer:
            type: string
            length: 20
            nullable: false
        beschreibung:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        faktor: 
            type: decimal
            precision: 2
            scale: 1

    uniqueConstraints:
        version_nr_unique:
           columns: nummer

    oneToMany:
        Aufgaben:
            targetEntity: Aufgabe
            mappedBy: Version

    [...]
```

Aufgabe:

```
evenos\Bundle\TimeBundle\Entity\Aufgabe:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: evenos\Bundle\TimeBundle\Repository\AufgabeRepository
    table: aufgabe

    id: 
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 40
        beschreibung:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        faktor: 
            type: decimal
            precision: 2
            scale: 1
        soll_aufwand:
            type: integer

    oneToMany:

        [...]

    manyToOne:

        [...]

        Version:
            targetEntity: Version
            inversedBy: Aufgaben
            joinColumns:
                - name: projekt_nummer
                  nullable: true
                  referencedColumnName: projekt_nummer
                - name: version_id
                  nullable: true
                  referencedColumnName: id
```

In my `AufgabeRepository` I have a custom method `findAufgabenByProjektAndVersion($projekt = null, $version = null)` - if `$version` is a Version-object, it uses its ID `$version->getId()` for querying, otherwise it searches `"[...] where version is null"`.

**The problem:** Because the association from `Aufgabe` to `Version` is optional (`nullable: true`), sometimes `$whatever->getAufgabe()->getVersion()` is `null`. Or rather should be. Instead, when I pass this to my repository function and the `Aufgabe` has no `Version` set, I get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/manuel/project/zeiterfassung/dev/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__evenosBundleTimeBundleEntityVersion.php line 54
```

I looked into the proxy class and the line mentioned is:

```
public function getId()
{
    if ($this->__isInitialized__ === false) {
        return (int) $this->_identifier["id"];
    }
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getId();
}
```

Obviously the proxy object isn't initiallized ... but should not `..->getAufgabe()->getVersion()` return `NULL` if this `Aufgabe` has no `Version` assigned?

Because it's not null but an uninitialized proxy, my custom finder function thinks it's a valid version ...

...

Somwhere, I am doing something terribly wrong, I fear, but I'm not seeing it right now :)
Maybe I've missread something and `nullable: true` isn't allowed for associations?

**Update:** My `findAufgabenByProjektAndVersion` method in the `AufgabeRepository`:

```
public function findAufgabenByProjektAndVersion(Projekt $projekt = NULL, Version $version = NULL)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()->addSelect('A')
            ->from('evenosTimeBundle:Aufgabe', 'A')
            ->leftJoin('A.Version', 'V'); 

    if (is_null($projekt))
    {
        $qb->where('A.Projekt is null');
    }
    else
    {
        $qb->where('A.Projekt is null OR A.Projekt = :projekt')->setParameter('projekt', $projekt);
    }

    if (is_null($version))
    {
        $qb->andWhere('V.nummer is null');
    }
    else
    {
        $qb->andWhere('V.nummer is null OR (V.Projekt = :vprojekt AND V.id = :vid)')
        ->setParameter('vprojekt', $projekt)
        ->setParameter('vid', $version->getId());
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I needed to query for the explicit `Version`-keys in the second `else` because Doctrine told me I couldn't search for `p.Version = :version` if it has a composite key (threw an error).

Comment: could you post the code of method "findAufgabenByProjektAndVersion" ?

Comment: I lately had a similar problem - maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275196/how-to-deal-with-doctrines-lazy-loading-when-having-null-objects

Comment: @Cyprian: updated my question with the method code.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: I found that one, too, and tried it out - unfortunately it didn't help :/

Comment: I've took a look on http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html and noticed that associationKey is set with ManyToOne relation (which is Aufgabe). It means that it hasn't it's own primary key, so this relation won't have any id field. The solution which should work for you will be use "generated" strategy and create primary keys for both entities

Comment: @Cyprian: Thank you for your input! I'm not sure I understand you, do you mean `Aufgabe` should get `Version` as an association key? I don't think that would work, because `Version` can be `null`, which doesn't make for a good identity. Also, `Aufgabe` already has a generated Id as a key ... could you maybe tell how you'd think the YAML mapping should be, please?